# How to select random column from dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select random value from data frame.

For example:

if `df=[a,b,c,d]` I want to select random from these 4 options

Comment: `df.sample`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments suggest you want to return a random `column` rather than random `row`. You can still achieve this using `df.sample()`. You just have to specify  the `axis`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : [1,2,3,4],                 
    'B' : [1,2,3,4],                 
    'C' : [1,2,3,4],  
    'D' : [1,2,3,4],                       
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

#Return random Column
df_Col = df.sample(axis=1)

#Return random Row
df_Row = df.sample()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select certain column you can to something similar to indexing in numpy .

```
df_new = df[2]
df_new = c 
print c[row_number]
```

First you select column you want the data value from . Let us say we want the value from column c so we index second column and put it into new dataframe .The call this new dataframe c . Now you have the column that you want your data from .Just type the row number in the code and you will get your desire value printed.

Comment: Actually I want to select random value from data not from particular column but random column. If I have [100,20,30,15] I want to select randomly from these values.

Comment: May be you are asking for df.sample()  that will give you some random row from your data  . You can  change value of n  to get as many random values you want  for example df.sample(n = 3)  will give you 3 random values from your data.