# Fill a random portion of the DataFrame with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How I can fill a random portion of the DataFrame with NaN values? I have a dataset with no gaps, 10% of which I want to fill with NaN values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select random column from dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383314/how-to-select-random-column-from-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: How exactly do you want to fill the dataset? with about 10%? Exactly 10%? By row/col or anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want **exactly** 10% of the items (well, to the nearest integer), you could use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with `replace=False` to generate a randomly ordered array of the first integers with the same shape as `df`, then use this as a mask to modify the DataFrame:

```
mask = np.random.choice(df.size, size=df.shape,
                        replace=False) < round(0.1*df.size)

df[mask] = np.nan
```

Example:

```
   A    B  C    D  E    F  G    H    I    J
0  X    X  X  NaN  X    X  X    X    X    X
1  X    X  X  NaN  X    X  X    X    X    X
2  X    X  X    X  X    X  X    X  NaN    X
3  X    X  X    X  X    X  X    X  NaN  NaN
4  X    X  X    X  X    X  X    X    X    X
5  X    X  X    X  X    X  X    X    X    X
6  X    X  X    X  X    X  X    X  NaN    X
7  X    X  X    X  X  NaN  X    X    X    X
8  X    X  X    X  X    X  X  NaN    X    X
9  X  NaN  X    X  X    X  X    X    X  NaN
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('X', index=range(10), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': range(1, 11), 'B': range(11, 21)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

num_nans = int(0.1 * df.size)
random_rows = np.random.choice(df.index, num_nans)
random_cols = np.random.choice(df.columns, num_nans)

df.loc[random_rows, random_cols] = np.nan
print(df.head())
```

Comment: I think the logic is flawed. You're using the total number of cells to define a sampling factor per row/columns. That will oversample. Even worse if the input is not square. Also your sampling creates duplicated columns/indices.

Answer (score 1):

One solution among others:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.random((10, 10))
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], data.shape, p=(0.1, 0.9))
data[mask] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```